# Get UIElement children from multiple parent

Tags: c#, wpf, uielement

I have a `StackPanel` with some `WrapPanel` . inside each `WrapPanel`  located two element:

```
<StackPanel FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Name="check_boxes_layout">
    <WrapPanel>
        <CheckBox Name="chk1" Checked="Checked_Changed" Unchecked="Unchecked"></CheckBox>
        <Rectangle Width="50" Fill="Red" Name="rec1" Margin="10 2 2 2"/>
    </WrapPanel>
    <WrapPanel>
        <CheckBox Name="chk12" Checked="Checked_Changed" Unchecked="Unchecked"></CheckBox>
        <Rectangle Width="50" Fill="Blue" Name="rec2" Margin="10 2 2 2"/>
    </WrapPanel>
<StackPanel/>
```

I want to get all children of type check box .how can i do this?

```
foreach (var item in check_boxes_layout.Children.OfType<CheckBox>())
{
    //this code just return Wrap Panel
}
```

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this recursive function:

```
List<UIElement> GetAllChildren(Panel c)
{
    List<UIElement> list = c.Children.Cast<UIElement>().ToList();
    foreach( var elem in list.OfType<Panel>())
        list.AddRange(GetChildren(elem));
    return list;
}
```

No you can say:

```
foreach (var item in GetAllChildren(check_boxes_layout).OfType<CheckBox>())
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it first loop through warp panels and get its child

```
 foreach (WrapPanel warppanel in check_boxes_layout.Children)
 {
     foreach (var item in warppanel.Children.OfType<CheckBox>)
     {
          .
          .
          .
     }
 }
```

Comment: What if you have another `Panel` or `Grid` inside the `WrapPanel`? My answer handles any level of nesting.

Comment: @MD.Unicorn, this (OP's) answer does answer OP's *current* question. None the less it's not a very good solution because it depends on the current layout: it will fail if new panels are introduced. That is, it's not future-proof.